# Help me fix the seams on my mesh

Tags: uv

I have unwrapped this model in blender but the seems are very visible in substance painter. How can i fix it? I want to achieve seamless texture.

[image]

[image]

Comment: is it your texture or is it your topology? If it's your texture you can try to give some corrections in the 3D view with the Clone brush?

Comment: I think it’s topology because I get the same problem with any texture I try to apply

Comment: in that case try to move the edge loop where it's happening (or delete and recreate it)

Comment: Check normals orientation, check if there are no internal faces there. Try removing doubles (select everything, M key).

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1

You should try to add subdivisions to that specific edge.

To do so go into *Edit Mode*. Select the edge by clicking on it, if you want to select and edge loop press <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>Click</kbd>, after you have selected the edges right click and the *Edge* context menu will appear, in the *Edge* context menu press *Subdivide*. You can also do this in the *Edge* menu at the top of the viewport or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>E</kbd>.

## Solution 2:

You should try smooth shading.

To do so you should, in *Object Mode*, you should select your object and then right click it and select *Shade Smooth*. Another way to do this is to select the *Object* menu at the top of the viewport and select shad smooth. If the problem continues to persist go into (while your object is still smooth shaded) the object data properties and select *Normals* and adjust the smooth shading to your needs. Turning off *Auto-Smooth* may also work but you need auto-smooth on to adjust the value.